# Same line,extracting 2 keywords

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

This is a follow-up to my previous question..not completely related,but kinda is..

I'm using Visual C# for my purpose..

Consider the following entries in my log file--

```
117.200.80.190 "2009-08-09 00:44:38  " "GET /admintools/openx-2.8.1/afr.php" 200 528 "http://www.enggresources.com/comedk/comedk_mock_counselling.php" "Mozilla/4.0"

59.92.139.141 - - "2009-08-09 00:56:50  " "GET /resources/ HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "http://www.enggresources.com/placements/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 "
```

-Now I want to extract "admintools" and "comedk" from the first entry..
-And "resources" and "placements" from the second entry..
-And "home" and "NULL" from the third entry..
-These are sample entries and I have similar thousands in my log file..

Once I extract each pair from each line, I'd like to be able to count the occurrence of the pair throughout the file.

Comment: LogParser: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use my [StringReader](http://webserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56552#671649).

```
string line = textReader.ReadLine();
var reader = new StringReader(line);
while (line != null)
{
    var ip = reader.ReadWord();
    reader.SkipWhitespaces();
    var date = reader.ReadQuotedString();
    reader.SkipWhitespaces();
    var uri = reader.ReadQuotedString();
    reader.ReadUntil('"');
    var uri2 = reader.ReadQuotedString();

    line = textReader.ReadLine();
    reader.Assign(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@"\"GET\s+/([^/]+)/\S*(?:\s+HTTP/1\.1)?\"\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\"https?://www.enggresources.com/([^/]+)"
```

Answer (score -1):

If I was you, I would try using Regular Expression

Comment: That's like saying "If I were you I would create a really cool parser". doesn't really help.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Next time add an example and you'll get up votes instead.